# Clicking links within subdirectory proxy_pass return 404 NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ghost-blog

Ok I'll try explain this as best I can. I've managed to setup to a subdirectory location `/blog/` on the `example.com` server block (Website A) that successfully displays my blog on the subdomain `blog.example.com.au` server block (Website B), with the url as `example.com/blog/`.

However when I click any of the links on the homepage from `example.com/blog/`, it shows a 404 of Website A when it should link to an article on Website B.

Desired behaviour:
`example.com/blog/article` links to `blog.example.com/article` while displaying `example.com/blog/article`

Actual behaviour:
`example.com/blog/article` links to `example.com/article` while displaying `example.com/article` 404

**I want to make sure `/blog/` appears on every request to be passed to Website B through the `/blog/` location block.**

Here is my current server block for website A to serve the blog on website B:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

...

  location ^~ /blog/ {
      proxy_pass https://blog.example.com.au/;
      proxy_set_header Host blog.example.com.au;
  }

  # This is needed to correctly serve static files for Website B and not have same 404 behaviour as explained above
  location /assets/ {
     proxy_pass https://blog.example.com.au/assets/; 
}

  # This is needed to correctly serve static files for Website B and not have same 404 behaviour as explained above
  location /content/ {
    proxy_pass http://blog.example.com.au/content/;
  }
}
```

If it helps Website A and B are both reverse proxied and working perfectly on their own in the same conf file:

```
upstream Website_A {
  server Website_A:8000;
}

upstream Website_B {
    server Website_B:2368;
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your backend with the correct base URL so it generates the correct links.

Since you seem to be using Ghost for your blog, [the option is called `url`](https://ghost.org/docs/concepts/config/).

```
"url": "https://example.com.au/blog/"
```

Of course it would make more sense to proxy this directly to ghost instead of proxying it twice.

```
server {
    server_name example.com.au;

    # ...

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass http://Website_B:2368;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great that worked when removing the trailing slash from `proxy_pass http://ghost`. But now I can't log in to the admin `Error: SQLITE_READONLY: attempt to write a readonly database`. My git push was raising a permission denied error earlier, so I changed the file permissions using `sudo chmod -R ug+w .;`. The permissions for ghost.db are now `-rw-r--r-- 1 michael michael`. Should I change the permissions of the `.db` file?

Comment: There is no way to know without more information. And this would be a new question. If this answer solved your problem please accept it using the checkmark on the left.